# How to include class files of dependencies in the generated build folder [GRADLE]

Tags: gradle, dependencies

When i run command "gradle assemble" on one of my intellij projects it creates the build folder with only class files of that specific project.
My project contains many dependencies from other projects.Is there any way to modify gradle file so that it generates dependencies class files too in the build folder?

Best Regards

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: so that i can import the build module in tomcat and run it as an application.Without it tomcat asks for many dependencies which i have to manually add

Comment: I don't get it. 
You could use the https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html gradle plugin to build a `war`. 

Posting your `build.gradle ` and project structure would help a lot.